# Batch File Help: Sorting files into specifically-named folders based on filename with exceptions

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, move, delimiter

My operating system is Windows 7 and I have files with names such as:

```
123.txt
abcd_123.txt
abcd_1234.txt
bcde_123_456.txt
bcde_123_4567.txt
cde_fgh_123_456.txt
cde_fgh_123_4567.txt
```

I would like for folders to be generated based on the starting parts of these filenames (or without the trailing numbers) and prefaced with a specific character, and for the files to then be sorted accordingly into them. Example result:

```
@abcd\abcd_123.txt
@abcd\abcd_1234.txt
@bcde\bcde_123_456.txt
@bcde\bcde_123_4567.txt
@cde_fgh\cde_fgh_123_456.txt
@cde_fgh\cde_fgh_123_4567.txt

*123.txt is skipped / not sorted.
```

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
@echo OFF
    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var_dir="#Sorted"

for /f "delims=_" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.txt') do (
 mkdir "#Sorted\@%%i" 2>nul
 move "%%i_*.txt" "%var_dir%\@%%i" >NUL 2>nul
)

echo Sorting Complete!
@pause

GOTO :EOF
```

It works, but I am not sure how to:

- Ignore filenames that start with a number (0-9).
- Obtain strings beyond the first delim (_).

As for the second point, I think the filenames can sometimes be too complex to correctly differentiate which part to use as the name for the folder. Example, it sorts:

```
cde_fgh_123_4567.txt
```

Into:

```
@cde\cde_fgh_123_4567.txt
```

As such, I was thinking for the algorithm to be something like:

```
Set Folder Name to 
(1) string before (first) "_" if string is greater than 3 characters 
OR
(2) entire string before second "_" if first string is less than or equal to 3 characters
```

Thus, the example above should be changed to:

```
@cde_fgh\cde_fgh_123_4567.txt
```

How do I improve my batch code to obtain the desired outcome?

Comment: Does your example show the applicable number of characters per part? To check if `%string%` is longer than 3 characters you could do this: `if not "%string:~3%"=="" echo String is longer than 3 chars`

Comment: to ignore files starting with `0-9` do `('dir /b /a-d *_*.txt' ^|findstr /rvbc:"[0-9]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\#Sorted"

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through matching files:
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%A in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*_*.txt"') do (
        rem // Skip if file name consists of less than two `_`-separated parts:
        if not "%%B"=="" (
            rem // Check if file name consists of more than two parts:
            if "%%C"=="" (
                rem // Two parts, so part one becomes directory name:
                2> nul md "@%%A"
                move "%%A_%%B" "@%%A\%%A_%%B"
            ) else (
                rem // More than two parts:
                set "ONE=%%A"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Check length of part one:
                if "!ONE:~3!"=="" (
                    rem /* Part one contains not more than 3 characters,
                    rem    hence parts one and two become directory name: */
                    endlocal
                    2> nul md "@%%A_%%B"
                    move "%%A_%%B_%%C" "@%%A_%%B\%%A_%%B_%%C"
                ) else (
                    rem /* Part one contains more than 3 characters,
                    rem    hence only part one becomes directory name: */
                    endlocal
                    2> nul md "@%%A"
                    move "%%A_%%B_%%C" "@%%A\%%A_%%B_%%C"
                )
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I incorporated a reply from a @Gerhard above [To use ('dir /b /a-d *_*.txt' ^|findstr /rvbc:"[0-9]") to skip numbers] into your code and made further modifications as I discovered additional cases to account for.

Answer (score 2):

Your specifications are not clear enough. I *assumed* that the folder name is comprised of the first parts of filename that are not numbers. This method works with your filename examples:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   call :getFolder "%%~Na"
   if defined folder (
      if not exist "!folder!\" mkdir "!folder!"
      move "%%a" "!folder!"
   )
)
goto :EOF


:getFolder filename
set "file=%~1"
rem Separate filename in parts at undescores and
rem collect them while part is not a number (greater than zero)
set "folder="
set "part=%file:_=" & set /A "num=part" & (if !num! equ 0 set "folder=!folder!_!part!") & set "part=%"
if defined folder set "folder=@%folder:~1%"
exit /B
```

For example, this is the result obtained with your data:

```
File "123.txt" folder ""
File "abcd_123.txt" folder "@abcd"
File "abcd_1234.txt" folder "@abcd"
File "bcde_123_456.txt" folder "@bcde"
File "bcde_123_4567.txt" folder "@bcde"
File "cde_fgh_123_456.txt" folder "@cde_fgh"
File "cde_fgh_123_4567.txt" folder "@cde_fgh"
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I saw @aschipfl's reply early on and was doing research to improve on that before returning to this post. Sorry for not being clear enough. Originally I wanted to skip any filename that started with a number, but ultimately I learned I can do as you assumed. I'm learning more from your response, so thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You could quickly do this using this code:

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_SrcFolder=C:\Admin\CMD\s-e\tmp"
  REM Use for DIR to pre-filter the list as much as possible
  SET "_FileGlob=*_*.txt"
  REM Used for FindStr Matches a Value that Begins with non numeric characters, followed by an underscore multiple times, followed by any number of numeric characters and underscore and ending in .txt
  SET "_FileRegex=!_SrcFolder:\=\\!\\[a-Z][a-Z_]*_[0-9][0-9_]*.txt$"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  REM Loop through the file sin the directory filtering non-matches and then perform actions based on matches
  ECHO."%_FileRegex%"
  FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
    DIR /S/B/A-D "%_SrcFolder%\%_FileGlob%" ^|
      FINDSTR /r "%_FileRegex%"
  ') DO (
    SET "_FileName=%%~nA"
    REM Break File Name after the Characters needed for the directory
    FOR /F "TOKENS=* delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_" %%a IN (
      "%%~nA"
    ) DO (
      REM Create Folder
      IF NOT EXIST "%_SrcFolder%\@!_FileName:_%%a=!\" (
        ECHO.&ECHO.== Creating Folder "@!_FileName:_%%a=!"
        MD "%_SrcFolder%\@!_FileName:_%%a=!\"
      )
      REM Move Original File to the New Directory 
      ECHO. + Moving "%%~nxA" TO "@!_FileName:_%%a=!"
      MOVE /Y "%%A" "%_SrcFolder%\@!_FileName:_%%a=!\%%~nxA" >NUL
    )
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I saw @aschipfl's reply early on and was doing research to improve on that before returning to this post. From what I've learned, I believe I understand what most of your code does and it's furthering my understanding of this topic. So thanks again!